# Adding admob to app. How to change target SDK to 3.2?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-manifest, admob

I added the following to the manifest:

```
       <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"                
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|
   uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

I downloaded API-13 (android 3.2) in SDK-Manager.

I added "android:targetSdkVersion="13"" to the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="13"  android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
```

But I see error, marked with red, for the following:
"uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

I use IntelliJ IDEA 11.

I changed Android SDK to 3.2 in file-project_structure-SDKs,
but I still see red error in manifest for "uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize".
Also "Theme.Dialog" became error marked with red in the following:

```
<activity android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
              android:label="@string/select_device"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

So what to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this error affect your app in any way? Could be a validation issue with IDEA editor, not a problem with your app.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the build SDK like this:
right click on the project -> properties -> Android -> and there you can choose your Build target.

or you could change it in your project.properties file. Just change the API Level in what ever comes after `target=android-[API Level here]`

If you want to use AdMob you have to set it to >= API Level 13

Comment: "project -> properties -> Android -> " - I could not find such menu. I use IntelliJ IDEA 11. Perhaps you are talking about Eclipse.

Comment: Yes I assumed you would use Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Or you can directly change the project.properties file to have e.g. `target=android-13`.

Comment: Nop. It does not work. It seems default.properties with "target=android-7" line is Eclipse's file.(I imported the project from Eclipse to IntelliJ)